# How to split a string in x equal pieces in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string in ruby like this:

```
str = "AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJ01020304050607080910"
# 20 letters and 20 numbers in this case
```

I want to split this in half, which I can do like this:

```
str[0, str.length/2]
```

or

```
str.split(0, str.length/2)
```

After that, I need to make arrays with the chars but with length 2 for each element like this:

```
["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH", "II", "JJ"],
[01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10]
```

The problem is, I can't find a concise way to convert this string. I can do something like this

```
arr = []
while str.length > 0 do
  arr << str[0, 1]
  str[0, 1] = ""
end
```

but I rather want something like `str.split(2)`, and the length of the string may change anytime.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How about this?

```
str.chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
```

Comment: A quick-and-dirty benchmark (Ruby 1.9) shows the is about 3 times slower than the `scan`-based benchmark.

    > Benchmark.measure { SecureRandom.hex(12_000_000).scan(/.{,7}/) }
    =>   2.280000   0.090000   2.370000 (  2.362817)
    
    > Benchmark.measure { SecureRandom.hex(12_000_000).chars.each_slice(8).map(&:join) }
    =>   6.780000   0.240000   7.020000 (  7.015237)

Comment: The `scan(/.{100}/)` method will leave off the last piece smaller than 100 chars, so I see some people suggesting `scan(/.{1,100}/)` instead, but this is erratic, and sometimes splits at odd boundaries in long strings. This each_slice method worked much more reliably for me.

Answer (score 20):

You could use the [scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) method:

```
1.9.3p194 :004 > a = 'AABBCCDDEEC'
 => "AABBCCDDEEC" 
1.9.3p194 :005 > a.scan(/.{1,2}/)
 => ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "C"]
```

Comment: this worked too, but i prefer the @MichaelKohl way thanks, anyway

Comment: No worries, I just thought it was worth posting this answer, as it uses just a method instead of three. But whatever fits you is allright :)

Comment: Very nice! Since you can interpolate regular expressions like strings, you could even use it like this: `scan(/.{1,#{size}}/)`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKohl !! I hadn't thought about the interpolation thing, it's always a pleasure to learn from people with a deep knowledge like you :) By the way, could you explain me, in brief, what `&:join` means in your answer?

Comment: Sure: `str.chars.each_slice(2)` returns an `Enumerator` for the string, which will yield a 2 element array. We then `map` over the arrays and `join` the two single-letter strings together. `&:join` uses the `Symbol#to_proc` shortcut. The long form would be `map { |arr| arr.join }`.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelKohl. I've learnt Ruby by Rails, but every day I realize that is such a powerful language and should take a closer look at it

Answer (score 0):

`2.1.0 :642 > "d852".scan(/../)
 => ["d8", "52"]`

Comment: Hi! Do you think you'd be able to elaborate so that OP has enough information to learn from your answer?